# Error while granting select privilege

Tags: oracle

Can anyone tell what is the wrong with the following statement?

`grant select on emp(ename,empno,deptno,job) to C##abc;`

It gives error.

Comment: Please post the error message.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to grant privileges on specific columns, but you can not do that for `SELECT`.

[image]

[Restriction on Object Privileges](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/GRANT.htm#d397288e1267)

> **column**
>
> Specify the table or view column on which privileges are to be
>   granted. You can specify columns only when granting the INSERT,
>   REFERENCES, or UPDATE privilege.

Comment: can u pls show how to user command